# Using DocuSign API and Ruby

Tags: ruby, docusignapi

I am getting started with Docusign, and even with Ruby. I am trying to get my head wrapped around something and I need your help.

I am trying in Ruby to create a helper in order to prefill a contract with the information I posses such as the client's information etc. And have that sent to the 2 people who need the contract. I am a little stuck in the steps I need to take in order to get the communication working and grabbing the information I need.
Any help or tips is appreciated.

I have installed the gem for the docusign API, I have the docusign-ruby-client code, I have also created my template, got my integrator key. I am stuck with the next step. How do I actually use in my project all these things together in order to automatically fill in the template with the information from the client ? –

EDITS: 
I am unsure on how to use this below in order to get my template, fill it automatically with my client info, and when done, send the pre-filled contract to 2 people.

```
    host = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi'
integrator_key = 'e5fdb0cd-a206-4934-91f1-5d00000000'
user_id = 'myemail@gmail.com'
expires_in_seconds = 3600 #1 hour
auth_server = 'account-d.docusign.com'
private_key_filename = '[REQUIRED]'

# STEP 1: Initialize API Client
configuration = DocuSign_eSign::Configuration.new
configuration.host = host

api_client = DocuSign_eSign::ApiClient.new(configuration)
api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow(private_key_filename, auth_server, integrator_key, user_id, expires_in_seconds)

# STEP 2: Initialize Authentication API using the API Client
authentication_api = DocuSign_eSign::AuthenticationApi.new(api_client)


# STEP 3: Make the login call
login_options = DocuSign_eSign::LoginOptions.new
login_information = authentication_api.login(login_options)

if !login_information.nil?
    login_information.login_accounts.each do |login_account|
        if login_account.is_default == "true"
            # STEP 4: Extract the user information
            base_url = login_account.base_url
            account_id = login_account.account_id

            puts base_url
            puts account_id

            # IMPORTANT: Use the base url from the login account to update the api client which will be used in future api calls
            base_uri = URI.parse(base_url)
        api_client.config.host = "%s://%s/restapi" % [base_uri.scheme, base_uri.host]
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far. Otherwise this question is too broad and you may find people downvote it.

Comment: Thank you ! I have installed the gem for the docusign API, I have the docusign-ruby-client code, I have also created my template, got my integrator key. I am stuck with the next step. How do I actually use in my project all these things together in order to automatically fill in the template with the information from the client ?

Comment: Please edit your qs and share the code what you have tried, and what you are expecting. No one will be able to share the example of how to use DS API with Ruby, you can check Ruby Test Cases with DocuSign [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-ruby-client/blob/master/tests/spec/unit_tests_spec.rb)

Comment: This added information (your comment) should be added to your original question (just click on 'edit'). I'm sorry but this is not my field, and I won't be able to solve your issue. Luckily there are many talented people here who may.

Comment: I really hope that key is bogus because it's now on the internet for all to see.

Comment: @tadman Yes it has been modified

Comment: do you still need help on this?